# SQL SELECT statement with dynamic column names

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try to select columns which names are the content of other columns. I'm using MySQL 5.6.

Let's say I have "table1":

```
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  id  |  val_int1  |  val_int2  |  val_string1  |  val_string2  |
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1   |  70        |  88        |  xxx          |  yyy          |
+------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

And "table2":

```
+------+--------+----------+
|  id  |  type  |  ref_id  |
+------+--------+----------+
|  10  |  i1    |  1       |
|  20  |  s2    |  1       |
+------+--------+----------+
```

What I want to do is: join table1 and table2, the table2.type field contains the name of the column from table1 which I want to select. And then there's the problem that the type field only contains abbreviations which I have to extend.
This ends up in the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    IF(t2.type REGEXP 'i[0-9]+', REPLACE(t2.type, 'i', 'val_int'), REPLACE(t2.type, 's', 'val_string'))
FROM
    table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE
    t1.id = t2.ref_id AND t1.id = 1
```

The result is that the REPLACE functions return val_int1 and val_string2 as fixed strings and not handle it as column names.

What I really expect is:

```
+-----+-------+
|  1  |  70   |
|  1  |  yyy  |
+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some sort of `case` expression:

```
select t1.id,
       (case when t2.type = 'i1' then cast(val_int_1 as varchar(255))
             when t2.type = 'i2' then cast(val_int_2 as varchar(255))
             when t2.type = 's1' then val_string_1
             when t2.type = 's2' then val_string_2
        end) as val
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

You are likely to complain "oh, I have so many columns".  Basically, too bad.  You have a poor database design.  You are trying to do a partial match on strings and column names.  Even a dynamic SQL solution is not very feasible.

Comment: I chose the second solution, because you can do without subqueries here. A note: Under MySQL 5.6 it is not possible to cast to VARCHAR.

Comment: @altralaser . . . The question is not tagged for MySQL.

Comment: It's not explicitly tagged, but I definitely wrote it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Using case expression, this is how i would solve this:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    id INT,
    val_int1 INT,
    val_int2 INT,
    val_string1 NVARCHAR(100),
    val_string2 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(1,70,88,'xxx','yyy')

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    id INT,
    type NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ref_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
(10,'i1',1),
(20,'s2',1)

SELECT 
    id,
    CASE WHEN type = 'i1' THEN CAST((SELECT TOP 1 val_int1 FROM @table1) AS NVARCHAR(100)) ELSE 
        CASE WHEN type = 'i2' THEN CAST((SELECT TOP 1 val_int2 FROM @table1) AS NVARCHAR(100)) ELSE 
        CASE WHEN type = 's1' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 val_string1 FROM @table1) ELSE 
            (SELECT TOP 1 val_string2 FROM @table1) END END END
FROM @table2 t2
```

OUTPUT:

```
10  70
20  yyy
```